# How to store a number string in a file as a seperate integer in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, readfile, c-strings

I have 32 bits as a text file in Sender.txt like

```
00100100101110001111111100000001
```

I want to store each individual number as an integer in the array. I have tried the following code but not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
  FILE *myfile;
  myfile = fopen("Sender.txt" , "r");
  char data[32];
  int i,con, data1[32];

  for(i=0;i<32;i++)
  {
    fscanf(myfile, "%1s", &data[i]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<32;i++)
  {
    con = atoi(data[i]);
    data1[i]=con;   
  }

  for(i=0;i<32;i++)
  {
    printf("%d \n", &data1[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d \n", &data1[i]);` --> `printf("%d \n", data1[i]);`

Comment: Your first problem: `atoi(data[i])` converts the whole string from the character `i` to the end. Your second problem: this string is either not NULL-terminated, or expands beyond the array boundary. Your third problem: you assign an integer number to a character. All three problems are in the same loop, and there may be more problems elsewhere. But, in the first place, your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still without fully understanding the purpose of your endeavor, I suggest to rewrite the first two loops:

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    int next = fgetc(myfile);
    data1[i] = (next == '0') : 0 ? 1;   
}
```

This code assumes that the file has 32 1's or 0's, all on the same line, and nothing else.

This could be further compressed, possibly at the expense of clarity:

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    data1[i] = fgetc(myfile) - '0';   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `fgetc` ? This function reads only one Charakter and returns it. 
Your code should then look like this:
**This one got errors see EDIT**

```
FILE *file;
char c[32];
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    if((c[i] = fgetc(file)) == NULL)
        //then Error
}
fclose(file);
```

**EDIT:** As rightly pointed out by "alk" (what a name mate xD) The if clause makes no sense at all. It was to early in the morning i apologize. The right code should of course look like this:

```
FILE *file;
int data[32];    //The Question was to store the Data in an int not char like i did...
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)      
    data[i] = fgetc(file) - '0';
fclose(file);
```

Best regards

Comment: there are more than that meets the eye.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`. On error it returns `EOF`. More over it does not return a pointer, so comparing to `NULL` (the null-pointer literal) does not make sense.